# UniTransaction throwing NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, u2, unidata, pick, uniobjects

I'm trying to begin a transaction however on calling the `.Begin()` method throws a NullReferenceException and the stacktrace shows that it is coming from `IBMU2.UODOTNET.UniTransaction.ServerTransaction(Int32 aKey)`.

Has anyone successfully used `UniTransaction`, if so is there something that i'm missing?

```
// note: Session is already connected 
// and can do UniFile operations prior to this point.

UniTransaction transaction = session.CreateUniTransaction();
transaction.Begin(); // throws NullReferenceException
```

Note: The system is a UniData system and not a UniVerse system. Not sure if that makes a difference.

[**Update 2011-07-08**] Still having this issue. We are using UniData version 7.2 (I think 7.2.6 specifically) and using the UniObjects.NET version 2.2.3.7377.

Comment: See my update below. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** There has been a fix for the UO.NET Transaction Object as of version 2.2.5

You can download the lastest version in the Nov-2011 [U2 Clients download](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/resources/downloads).

IF that doesn't solve your issue, please get in contact with your support provider. I see no open bugs in system that relate to this issue.

---

Are you able to supply more code?

As a start, maybe moving the `session.CreateUniTransaction` before you do the `session.CreateUniFile`.

Not sure if it will help (because we are currently using the COM UniObjects not the .NET library), but that is how they have it in the example in uonet.pdf

Comment: the only other code is the login, password, and the connect call for the unisession object. after that i just use the above code and it throws the error. I'm thinking it is a UniData issue. Could it be that our version of UniData doesn't support transactions? or only UniVerse can support transactions?

Comment: Hmmm. I'll do some checking. We are using v6. Maybe it needs to be turned on or is a config setting in UniData?